# Android load library error -- failed to map segment

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I am loading a native library using JNI. The library resides on the sdcard.

I am loading the library with this code:

```
try
        {
            File str;
            String storage;
            str = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            storage = str.getAbsolutePath();

            File f = new File(storage+"/Android/data/org.ilri.IMPACTLight/libIMPInterface.so");
            if (f.exists())
                System.load(storage+"/Android/data/org.ilri.IMPACTLight/libIMPInterface.so");
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            Log.i(QtTAG, "Security: Can't load /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/org.ilri.IMPACTLight/libIMPInterface.so", e);
        }
        catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
        {
            Log.i(QtTAG, "Link: Can't load /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/org.ilri.IMPACTLight/libIMPInterface.so", e);
        }
```

However I always get:

> D/dalvikvm(  408): Trying to load lib
>   /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/org.ilri.GPSTest/libGPSInterface.so
>   0x44ede2c0 I/dalvikvm(  408): Unable
>   to
>   dlopen(/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/org.ilri.GPSTest/libGPSInterface.so):
>   Cannot load library:
>   load_segments[907]: 33 failed to map
>   segment from 'libGPSInterface.so' @
>   0x81900000 (0x00003470).
>   p_vaddr=0x00000000 p_offset=0x00000000

I get this on a AVD 2.2

Any idea how to solve this is much appreciated!!!

Thanks,
Carlos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot load native libraries or execute binaries located on the SDCard. It is mounted noexec.

You need to copy the library to the internal storage before you load it, that is, in a *subdirectory* of `dataDir`, eg:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
String dataDir = pm.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).dataDir;
// Create a directory like dataDir/mylibs/ and copy the library in it
```

Comment: You can copy the file with Java, or with native code, it doesn't matter. Just copy the file into internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

Add your .so file inside your application and use the following..

```
System.loadLibrary("libIMPInterface.so");
```

Comment: Do you mean as part of the apk?

Comment: I don't think you can use "libIMPInterface.so". Rather, you'd use "IMPInterface". But you also can use System.load("fullname"), as the OP did.